# Eliminar y editar mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Tengo unos datos guardados en una base de datos mongodb
Hice un botón de eliminar pero no se como hacer para eliminar un registro o editarlo

```
<?php 

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use MongoDB\Client as Mongo;
    $mongo = new Mongo();

    //$mongo = new Mongo();
    $db = $mongo->Directorio;
    //$db = $mongo->selectDB("librosdb");

    $c_autores = $mongo->selectCollection($db,"Coordinacione");
    //$autores = $librosdb->autores;
    //$c_autores = $autores->find()->toArray();

?>
```

el método iría ahí, pero no se como usarlo en el index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré este ejemplo en internet, espero te sea de utilidad:

```
// Using MongoDB\Driver\Manager

$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->delete(['topic_name' => ""Delete MongoDB Document""], ['limit' => 1]);
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$result = $manager->executeBulkWrite('database.myCollection', $bulk);

// Using PHP Library

$con = new MongoDB\Client(""mongodb://localhost:27017"");
$db = $con->databaseabi_db;
$collection = $db->myCollectiontopic;
$delRec = $collection->deleteOne(
['topic_name' => ""Delete MongoDB Document""], ['limit' => 1]
);
```

https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-delete-mongodb-document-using-php-278